# Is is a good idea to track package lock files (e.g. NPM's package-lock.json) in Git LFS?

Tags: npm, nuget, locking, git-lfs

I noticed that the NPM-produced `package-lock.json` file in one of our projects is around 550 KiB in size. Likewise, the `packages.lock.json` files produced by NuGet are ~100 KiB and will likely grow.

I'm interested in keeping our Git repositories compact, so I was wondering: **Since these files change frequently and are relatively large, does it make sense to track them in Git LFS?**

I realize that Git won't be able to auto-merge changes if they are tracked in Git LFS, but aren't the lock files easily regenerated, generally speaking?

Answer (score 1):

Lock files are easily regenerated. That doesn't mean you *should* regenerated them. A package-lock will tell you which exact versions of each dependency were used in that commit. This lets other contributors (and yourself) rebuild your project with exact the same dependencies, which avoids a lot of hassle when an updated dependency introduces a bug. You should treat package-lock as a configuration file for your project and keep it in code.

As to keeping it on git lfs, know that while package lock files do change often, their content is plain text formatted like code, which is exactly the type of content git is optimized to store/retrieve. E.g. git won't store each file separately, but rather chunks of package-lock that can be reused across commits.

All in all, I wouldn't worry too much about the perf impact of package-lock on your repo. Sure, there will be some, but it's an important configuration file and the benefits of committing it outweigh the drawbacks. Think about it this way: if you have a lot of code for your project, will that impact your git repo performance? Yes. Does that mean you shouldn't commit that code? Of course not--that's the whole point of using git.

Answer (score 0):

While `package-lock.json` are generated, it's usually a bad idea to track them via LFS.

The [npm documentation](https://github.com/npm/cli/blob/latest/docs/lib/content/configuring-npm/package-lock-json.md#description) tell us that the `package-lock.json`:

> Facilitate greater visibility of tree changes through readable source
> control diffs.

By tracking the lockfile via LFS, Github (and others) will not show you the diff of an LFS tracked file. You won't be able to search for change via `git log`.

In a pull-request, you can easily see the impact of adding/updating a dependency has on all your other dependencies. You won't be able to see that easily with LFS.

`package-lock.json` is a text file, which is what git can handle best.